# Consuming .net standard dll with ILogger in .net framework with nlog

Tags: .net, nlog, ilogger

I am working on a dll that is being created in .Net Standard to be consumed by both .net core and .net framework applications.

One of the requirements is to have logging within the dll, which can be implemented easily enough for the .net core applications by using the ILogger interface in microsoft.extensions.logging.

Is there any way to convert the ILogger implementation of NLog in .net framework to ILogger in microsoft.extensions.logging?